# implement acl on field in spring security

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-acl

I would like implement spring acl for my object fields.

does anyone has an idea what do i have to implment for it?

for example, i have Purchase object.

i would like admin_role to have read on all the fields, and secretary_role to have read only on username and address field

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify at what point you need the security?

If this is part of a webapp, I frequently use [stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Security+Interceptor+for+custom+authorization) security interceptors in combination with spring to control access to what the user *sees* based on role.

If it's not part of a webapp and you're looking to control what a user can *change* there's a number of methods available from custom annotations to database control. I've found the project itself usually dictates which path I should follow.

Comment: hi!

it's a web application.

I use jsf. and i need to secure the object fields that are displayed on the screen.
for example, i have an object called worker. i will display a list of workers in a table. 
if the role that entered is admin_role, he will view all the fields.
it the role that entered is a secretary_role, he will view only the name and address field (i don't want him to see the salary of the worker).

Answer (score 0):

extend org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission and introduce your own Permission flag (up to 32 bits are supported)